# I need to use places SDK to show the user specified items in a List

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hii Friends please help me. I need to use SDK for list near places such as atm, bank, restaurant within user-defined circle.My code are below. Please help me for list the items in Recyclerview.

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
double lat, lon;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        } else {

            String[] mPermission = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, mPermission, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        }
    } else {
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {

                            lat = location.getLatitude();
                            lon = location.getLongitude();

                            LatLng CurrntLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CurrntLocation, 19);  

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CurrntLocation).title("Current Position"));  
                            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                        }
                    }
                });
    } }   }
```

Comment: Use Place SDK then.

Comment: How can use it. I dont how to use it. I tired many tutorials in last one week. Please help me to solve it. Its very urgent Brother.

Comment: Anyone to know about it. Please respond !!!